# How to install Drush 8 on Windows 10?

Tags: 8, drush

I am currently running Drush 7 and its working fine for D7.

But I want to run it for D8 site. I have also seen many post where it is mentioned that Drush 7 support D8 but its not true.

So i am trying to install Drush 8.

Try to run below command

```
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

Or

```
composer require drush/drush:dev-master
```

./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].
>       - drush/drush dev-master requires consolidation/robo dev-master -> satisfiable by consolidation/robo[dev-master] but these conflict with
>   your requirements o r minimum-stability. Installation failed, deleting
>   ./composer.json.

But unable to get success. Any suggestion how achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally...

using this command

```
 composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

But i need to refer few steps before running this command.

```
  composer.json  # Removed the line containing drush like below
```

> {
>           "require": {
>               <del>"drush/drush": "7.*"</del>
>           }
>       }

```
composer global update
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

source https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2006